# Increment variable in loop, unexpected result

Tags: java

Code snippet:

```
int i=0;

for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
    i=--i-i--;
    System.out.println("for loop i= "+i);
}
System.out.println("i value outside for loop= "+i);
```

output:

```
for loop i= 0
i value outside for loop= 1
```

The value of i inside for loop is zero and outside for loop i is 1. Could you please help me understand it?

Comment: Note that you have two different `i` variables .

Comment: @Arnaud Not really. The correct thing to say is "this code won't compile". You can't have different variables with the same name within the same context, hence you cannot *have two different i variables*.

Comment: @BackSlash : You're right, then it would be better to have the actual code in the question.

Comment: Interestingly, the variable is block scoped to the for loop so in theory this code could be valid. If there is a Java compiler which accepts this code, then the loop is irrelevant. The i in the outer scope is never changed.

Answer (score 1):

`i=--i-i--;` changes the value of `i` to `-1` and then back to `0`, because it assigns to it `-1-(-1)`, which is `0`. The reason for this result is that pre-decrement operator - `--i` - returns the decremented value `-1` while post-decrement operator - `i--` - returns the value prior to decrementing it (therefore it returns `-1` instead of `-2`).

However, the loop's `i++` clause increments `i` to 1, which causes the loop to terminate. Therefore the value of `i` is `1` after the loop.

Note that you have a typo in your question. You are declaring `i` twice in the same scope. In order for the code to pass compilation (and display the output you claim you got), you should change it to:

```
int i=0;

for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    i = --i-i--;
    System.out.println("for loop i= "+i);
}
System.out.println("i value outside for loop= "+i);
```

Comment: And dropping the entire wonky `i=--i-i--;` will result in the exact same output, the 0 inside vs. 1 outside is just how `for` loops work.